# Creating linear models in R

Tags: r, regression, linear

So I have this data set `t.dat` with 31 observations and two groups (V5):

[image: tdat]

I'm interested in testing where we can say that the mean of $(V2,V3,V4)$ where we only take observations with $V5=2$ is equal to the mean of $(V2,V3,V4)$ where we only take observations with $V5=1$. So I wanna test if the two groups has the same mean vector through linear models (and anova) in R.

What we know about each group is that they are both $3$- dimensional normal distributed, so my current idea is to create a linear model with a design matrix $T=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ where $T$ is a $31\times 2$ matrix with $1$ on all entries in the first column and $1$ on the first $16$ entries and $0$ on the rest (which corresponds with the number of observations in the group with $V5=1$) and then use anova to see if we can reduce to a model with design matrix $\tilde{T}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$, so a design matrix with dimension $31\times 1$ with $1$ on all entries.

Is this correct and if so, how do I create those models in R with the `lm` function?

Thank you for your time and if you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: You may be interested in applying Hotelling's $T^2$ test or a MANOVA on your data.

Comment: So if I wanna use MANOVA I would create a linear model like this:
lm.fit <- manova(cbind(V2,V3,V4)~V5, data = t.dat)? Would I then call summary(lm.fit) or summary.aov(lm.fit)?

Comment: This command will give you the ifnormation you need: `summary(manova(cbind(V2, V3, V4) ~ V5, data = t.dat))`.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense! So MANOVA is the multivariate version of ANOVA?